# How could I create a fps=1 mp4 video using FFMpegWriter from matplotlib.animation?

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, ffmpeg

I would like to create a video to visualize a small dataset. This dataset contains only 10 or 20 frames of data, and I want to visualize it one frame a second and make a .mp4 video using FFMpegWriter.

But when I set fps=1, there is a long time black screen of the result video and only a still image. After that, this .mp4 ends. An example of code is as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.animation import FFMpegWriter

np.random.seed(0)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 4))
ln, = ax.plot([])
ax.set_xlim([0, 1000])
ax.set_ylim([-1, 1])
ax.grid(True)

writer = FFMpegWriter(fps=1)
with writer.saving(fig, "writer_test.mp4", 300):
    for i in range(20):
        x = np.arange(1000)
        t = np.random.randn(1000)
        y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)
        ln.set_data(x, y)
        writer.grab_frame()
plt.show()
```

If I change fps to 10, then the video flows well but end too soon. Can I grab and make videos one frame per second?

Comment: I've never used `matplotlib`'s `FFMpegWriter` but if you want to explorer different options, you can give my `ffmpegio` and its [mpl plugin](https://github.com/python-ffmpegio/python-ffmpegio-plugin-mpl).

Comment: Is `ffmepgio` a much faster solution in generating a movie in Python? I will give it a try!

Comment: I won't say it's faster. Speed is dictated by FFmpeg, which both uses. It's a little easier to configure IMO (ofc because I'm the dev). I'll convert your your example code and post a response here in a little bit

Comment: I found that it does not have a conda build yet, would it possible to add a conda receipt? Hmm, It is very similar to the FFMpegWriter syntax, which writes one frame a time.

Comment: Sorry, I have no plan of getting it out on conda atm. Yes, the concepts are the same (really there is no other way to approach it). It's just matter of which side you're coming from. If you don't need to read/write media files in r&d environment, `ffmpegio` isn't really needed. I must admit.

Comment: As for `FFmpegWriter`, assuming that it takes arbitrary ffmpeg options as arguments, you can try `r=1` instead of `fps=1` to see if you have a better luck. `-r` is an ffmpeg option t specify the framerate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented above, this is not so much different from `matplotlib` implementation, but you open the output file with specified framerate, which makes it easier to grasp imo.

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import ffmpegio

np.random.seed(0)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 4),dpi=300)
ln, = ax.plot([])
ax.set_xlim([0, 1000])
ax.set_ylim([-1, 1])
ax.grid(True)

with ffmpegio.open(
  "writer_test.mp4", # output file name
  "wv", # open file in write-video mode
  1, # framerate in frames/second
  pix_fmt="yuv420p", # specify the pixel format (default is yuv444p)
  overwrite=True
) as writer:
    for i in range(20):
        x = np.arange(1000)
        t = np.random.randn(1000)
        y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)
        ln.set_data(x, y)
        writer.write(fig)
```

You can add any ffmpeg output & global options as arguments to the `open()`.

Comment: Hi, you codes can generate a video. But I install your ffmpegio in my linux distribution (archlinux) , and strangely, the fps=1 option in matplotlib.FFMpegwriter works ... I do not know why there are differences between linux and windows.

Comment: BTW, there are 2 seconds of black screens at the start of the frame, do you have the same problem?

Comment: Just checked first frame of the generated video and the frame is not black